# Flex : difference between using HTTPService and URLRequest

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

What is the difference between using `HTTPService` and `URLRequest` for requesting your data from a flex page to servlet

Answer (score 2):

[URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) is the Request Object that contains the URL to load, the post parameters, etc. Usually it is used with more basic loader types than HTTPService, like URLLoader.

[HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html) takes the URL directly as one of its properties, so it doesn't need a URLRequest. Technically, you could use a URLRequest to provide the rest of the "payload," since it is an Object and the request parameter of HTTPService can be any Object.

Comment: Karan, if you hover your cursor over the blue text in my answer (URLRequest and HTTPService), you can click them and see the references.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPService is a higher level object, part of the Flex framework, not native to the Flash Player.

It implements various interfaces and can be used as an MXML tag, so you can bind UI controls directly to it. If you are working mostly in MXML, this is easier to use.

URLLoader is native to the Flash Player and is more low level.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. Could you both, please make some lill elaboration on both topics.. Or provide some source for the same