# flex httpservice not functioning

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I can't get my flex script to query https://domain.com/caller.php?focus=test123. I'm not trying to get a POST or GET reply. It simply needs to query the specified URL in service.url. So far I've (1) added the mx.rpc.http.HTTPService library, (2) assigned it the variable service: HTTPService, and lastly (3) I called it as seen below. The FLEX script compiles, but the FLEX script doesn't query the specified url on my webserver (note: this is an online web server where the compiled .swf is running in the same path as caller.php and it could also just query caller.php without https://domain.com/ if this is permitted).

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

        // httpservice
        private var service:HTTPService

        // rest of the code is omitted as its not relevant at all


    ]]>
</fx:Script>

    // rest of the code is omitted as its not relevant at all




        public function placeCall(identity:String):void
        {
            status("Calling " + calleeInput.text + "\n");
            service = new HTTPService();
            service.url = "https://domain.com/caller.php?focus=test123";
            service.send();

        // rest of the code is omitted as its not relevant at all

        }

    // rest of the code is omitted as its not relevant at all
```

Source if you want to see the omitted code and PRECISELY where I'm inserting HTTPservice: https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/blob/master/VideoPhone/src/VideoPhone.mxml#L375

Comment: i tried adding service.send(); but it didnt do anything

Comment: Not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve by hitting that URL? I am not seeing you add any event listeners for success or failure? And if its a simple URL you need to hit, then why not use URLLoader instead? P.S I looked at your code link above, but I could not find httpservice being used at all.

Comment: " P.S I looked at your code link above, but I could not find httpservice being used at all." Right because this is the original source code before my modifications as demonstrated above. Sounds like I need to use URLLoader instead like you suggested.

Comment: URL Loader worked thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using URLRequest resolved my issue. To learn about the differences see: [Flex : difference between using HTTPService and URLRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984806/flex-difference-between-using-httpservice-and-urlrequest)

```
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.domain.com/foo.php?focus=bar");
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlRequest);
```